# Align boxes and rotate boxes in plain TeX

Tags: positioning, boxes, characters, rotating, plain-tex

When I finish reading the Appendix D: Dirty Tricks in the TeXbook, I rethink a question: is it possible to align some character boxes like this:

[image]

The input may be like this:

```
    \font\fortyeightrm=cmr10 at48pt
    \font\twentyfourrm=cmr10 at24pt

    \parindent=0pt
    {\fortyeightrm A}|\twentyfourrm a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r|
    \bye
```

We assume that when TeX is scanning the big `A`, it will place that character box at the baseline of the first line. When scanning the `|`, it will enter a group, then TeX will place the character boxes `a`, `b`, `c`, ... , `r` above then below the axis of the character box `A` (at this time, TeX may be insert the line-break at the end of a line, for example, behind the character box `i`)

I haven't a good and simple method to solve this. Also another question: is it possible to rotate the character box (maybe we should put it into a `\hbox`) ?

Comment: Using (x)dvipdfm(x) (i.e., XeTeX) driver, the rotation could be: `before \special{pdf: begintransform rotate 35 } rotated \special{pdf: endtransform} after\bye`. But you're right, the content shouldn't be broken across pages according to the [dvipdfm manual](http://gaspra.kettering.edu/dvipdfm/dvipdfm-0.12.4.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 48pt and 24pt fonts is not a good idea, because the relevant dimension is the height of capitals. So the big letter should be in a larger size, in my opinion.

```
\font\highcapital=cmr10 at60pt
\font\twentyfourrm=cmr10 at24pt

\def\timlititle#1#2{%
  \hbox{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\highcapital #1}%
    \dimen0=\ht0
    \box0\vbox to\dimen0{
      \twentyfourrm
      \def\\{\egroup\nointerlineskip\vss\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces}%
      \hbox\bgroup#2\egroup}%
  }%
}

\hrule
\timlititle{A}
  {a b c d e f g h i \\
   j k l m n o p q r}

\bigskip

\font\highcapital=cmr10 at54pt

\hrule
\timlititle{A}
  {a b c d e f g h i \\
   j k l m n o p q r}

\bigskip

\font\highcapital=cmr10 at48pt

\hrule
\timlititle{A}
  {a b c d e f g h i \\
   j k l m n o p q r}

\bye
```

The `\hrule` commands are just to show the vertical alignment of the boxes. In Computer Modern, the "A" has quite a big overshoot at the top, so you may want to add a small correction for the right box height.

[image]

For rotating boxes, you can use `eplain`'s facilities to load the LaTeX `graphicx` package:

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\endpackages

\rotatebox{-45}{Abcdef}
```

Comment: yeah, the first of the three examples is more pleasing to the eyes. Thanks, egreg.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
    \font\fortyeightrm=cmr10 at48pt
    \font\twentyfourrm=cmr10 at24pt


\hsize 3in

\def\foo#1|#2|{%
\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
\dimen0\ht0
\advance\dimen0\dp0
\divide\dimen0 2
\leavevmode\raise -\dimen0 \hbox{\smash{\copy0}}\vtop{\advance\hsize-\wd0 #2}}

    \parindent=0pt

X\dotfill X

\bigskip

    \foo
    {\fortyeightrm A}|\twentyfourrm a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r|


\bigskip

X\dotfill X
    \bye
```

Comment: Wonderful! I think this method is simple and elegant to solve my question :-)